# How to remove zoom, terrain and user navigation from google map?

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am using the JS API to display my map.
Here is the code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  function initialize() {
        var _lat = 10;
        var _long = 200;
        var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(_lat, _long);
    var myOptions = {
      center: myLatlng,
      zoom: 15,
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    };
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"),
        myOptions);

        var image = 'target.png';
        var beachMarker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: myLatlng,
            map: map,
            icon: image
        });

        beachMarker.setMap(map);
  }
</script>
```

Now i want to remove few things from the map.

1. Remove the zoom controls + user should not be able to zoom using
   mouse or anything
2. User should not be able to move around the map using mouse. It
   should stay like a static image
3. Remove the MAP|SATELLITE option from map.

How do i achieve this.

[image]

Answer (score 63, accepted):

```
scrollwheel: false,
```

This option is used for disable zoom on mouse.

```
scaleControl: false,
```

This option is used for disable zoom by scale.

```
draggable: false,
```

This option is used for disabling drag.

```
mapTypeControl: false,
```

This option will hide map type.

Put them as following:

```
var myOptions = {
   center: myLatlng,
   zoom: 15,
   mapTypeControl: false,
   draggable: false,
   scaleControl: false,
   scrollwheel: false,
   navigationControl: false,
   streetViewControl: false,
   mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
};
```

Comment: Thanks for such a quick reply..  How do i remove this? [IMG]http://i.imgur.com/VKmkm.png[/IMG]

Comment: gmap.removeControl(); try this.

Comment: Got a solution for my question.. need to add the two..     navigationControl: false,
    streetViewControl:false

Answer (score 24):

Use the "disable default UI"
example:

```
var mapOptions = {
    zoom: 4,
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(-33, 151),
    disableDefaultUI: true,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
}

var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map-canvas"), mapOptions);`
```

Comment: This is the best answer to remove the requested items without having to list each individual option.

Comment: This removes the UI, but doesn't prevent users from scrolling/zooming using a mouse or touch controls.

Answer (score 19):

For remove + and - use this

zoomControl: false

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/controls